# Connect to multiple environments from the same ASP.NET MVC API

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, entity-framework

I read a lot of posts but can't figure out the best way to do the following:

I have an ASP.NET MVC API, containing multiple API verbs.

All of them are accessing my database but, in a near future, not all in the same environment.

e.g.:

- `POST` to `/api/v1/func1` is using the PROD database, with user `PRODUSR` and password `PRODPWD`
- `POST` to `/api/v1/func2` is using the ACCEPTANCE database with `ACCUSR` and `ACCPWD`
- `POST` to `/api/v1/func3` is using the TEST database with `TSTUSR` and `TSTPWD`

Why? Because I have only one IIS server and allowed by our IT team to only create one site. And the API will soon not be in the same state of development/test/prod depending on the function.

So, until now, when everything was in TEST, in my web.config, I had a section for my EF like so:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DBEntities" 
         connectionString="metadata=res://*/DBEntities.csdl|res://*/DBEntities.ssdl|res://*/DBEntities.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=testdb\inst01;initial catalog=APIDB;User Id=TSTUSR;Password=TSTPWD;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" 
         providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

In every environment, the DB schema is the same (could be otherwise).
Today, all are doing the same kind of usage of the EF:

```
Using db As New DBEntities
    ' Do something
    db.SaveChanges()
End Using
```

Is there an elegant way to connect each function to it's own EF context?

Cherry on the cake, if it is possible to change the behavior of each function by changing the web.config too, without having to change the code and do a new publish?

Comment: Personally, given those restrictions, I'd be inclined to create three separate applications within the one site, rather than trying to mix production, QA, and dev code in the same application.

Comment: Constraints are even worst than you might think. It is also who is using the API that add some. They test func1 for a few days/week. Then they just say: "from tomorrow, everything we send should be in production and we will start testing func2". And they don't want to change the called URL.

Answer (score 0):

You can have more than one connection string in web.config

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DBEntities_PROD" connectionString="metadata=res://*/DBEntities.csdl|res://*/DBEntities.ssdl|res://*/DBEntities.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string="data source=testdb\inst01;initial catalog=APIDB;User Id=TSTUSR;Password=TSTPWD;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework"" "providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    <add name="DBEntities_ACCEPTANCE" connectionString="metadata=res://*/DBEntities.csdl|res://*/DBEntities.ssdl|res://*/DBEntities.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string="data source=testdb\inst02;initial catalog=APIDB_02;User Id=TSTUSR;Password=TSTPWD;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework"" "providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    <add name="DBEntities_TEST " connectionString="metadata=res://*/DBEntities.csdl|res://*/DBEntities.ssdl|res://*/DBEntities.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string="data source=testdb\inst03;initial catalog=APIDB_03;User Id=TSTUSR;Password=TSTPWD;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework"" "providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Then you can create three contexts and use one or another inside your functions depending some condition you want (some key also in web config, some values in a json file, ...) and dont forget to use some context by default

Comment: To use one of the connection string, I'll do the usual "Using db As New DBEntities_PROD" for exemple, right? Will it work? Isn't it a implicit class created from the edmx? I'm not used to EF from DB. Or should I create as many edmx as the number of databases?